# Is it possible to open a bank account in Belgium with a Carte E or E+?

Tags: resident-permit, eu-citizens, banking

Is it possible to open a bank account in Belgium with only a "Carte E", which is given to non Belgian EU citizens?

Comment: I suspect you need a Belgian address.  Do you have one?

Comment: It's assumed that one with such a card has an address

Comment: Have you tried asking a bank there?

Comment: As Traveller said. I opened a bank account in the UK before I even lived there. No problems.